# How to mount a SMB volume owned by root as r/w and visible in the Finder on the Mac?

Tags: finder, mount, smb, ventura

Before you tell me all the security implications I am well aware and this is for convenience testing. I have a server running smbd on Debian 11 and it is configured correctly such that I can mount and use shares normally. However, I would like to share the server /root such that I can read and write files from my Mac which has the tools I like to use.

As root on my Mac using the following command:

```
mount_smbfs -f 666 -d 777 //root:xxxx@10.1.1.1/root /Volumes/root/
```

I can mount the root folder on the server and see and modify files as root on the Mac.
But the volume `root` is not visible from the Finder with hidden items turned on. The files are accessible from the terminal and emacs but I would like to be able to use for example SQLPro to examine some databases on the server but the volume is not accessible or visible from the Open dialog.

Comment: Finder isn’t run by root but by the logged in user.  By default, it wouldn’t show because of this.

Comment: Finder may not be owned by root but it can certainly see volumes owned by root. Entering `open /` will show the root which is owned by root.

Comment: And `/` isn’t mounted anywhere within Finder as a “clickable icon”.  It also depends on the permssions.  Try `open /tmp` and see if you get the same results.  It’s important to note I said “By default, it wouldn’t show” not that it can’t be shown.

Comment: That may be so and the default may be to not show but my question remains, how can I make it visible?

Comment: Either by AppleScript or with the shell, create a link on the desktop to the mounted volume.

Answer (score 0):

While the suggestion by Allan would work I just discovered that by accessing the server as I did in the question I can now see the same share when I connect as usual using the Finder which now shows me connected as root and the files in the volumes are owned by my user and thus visible and writable.